# Fail to show an error in my form with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my controller:

```
    public function Index()
{
     $this->load->model('InsertData');
       $this->InsertData-> validateField();
     $this->InsertData->DispalyForm();

}
```

This is my model:

```
     class InsertData extends CI_Model
 {
     function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->helper('form');
     }

     function DispalyForm()
     {
            $dataI = array(
                'name'        => 'topic',
                'id'          => 'url',
                'value'       => set_value('username'),
                'maxlength'   => '100',
                'size'        => '50',
                'style'       => 'yellow',
                );

            $dataS=array(
                'name' => 'submit',
                'value'=>'create topic'
            );

            $data['submit'] = form_submit($dataS);
            $data['textbox']= form_input($dataI);
            $this->load->view('admin',$data);
     }

     function validateField()
     {
         $this->load->library('form_validation');
         $rules['topic']='required';
         $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
         $this->form_validation->run();


   }
 }
```

The problem is whenever I submit the form and the field is empty nothing gets displayed.

I have at the top of my view this line:

```
       <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

Where is my code wrong..why no error is displayed whenver I submit the form?!!?

Answer (score 0):

When setting validation rules using an array, the array must be multi dimensional.

An array of rules, whereby each rule is an array of criteria.

See [this manual page](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrulesasarray) RE this issue.

```
$rules = array(
    array(
         'field'   => 'topic', 
         'label'   => 'Topic', 
         'rules'   => 'required'
    )
);

$this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
```